# Numerical Test Question

Tags: arithmetic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs2AR.jpg

The first method I used was find out Profits by
Sales Revenue - Operating Cost - Payroll Cost - Waste -Shrinkage

I have Geneva the lowest and the answer is wrong.

2nd method, I used sales revenue/number of employees
London was the lowest and it's wrong again.

Could anyone help me out on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method gives -57 for Geneva and -70 for Rome, so Rome would seem to be the answer.

Comment: Yes Rome is the right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they want the least profitable (but not a loss?) site.  I think your first calculation is the correct approach.  Or they could want profit/employee, but it looks like Geneva is still the biggest loser/employee (I didn't run the numbers, just guessed)

Comment: ok thanks. I will redo the test again.